# Angular 7 SSR - problems with NgZone

Tags: angular, webpack, server-side-rendering, zone.js, ngzone

I've recently moved my company's website from React to Angular, since most our projects were already on Angular 7. Being the "use-the-latest-and-greatest" person that I am, I decided to implement server-side rendering to get the  google page speed rating close to that 100/100 (currently 42/100). I've been tinkering with it for the better part of the week now, unsuccessfully - the latest roadblock has been especially hard for me to overcome. Here's a brief info about my setup, then I'll get into the details:

- NodeJS 8.9.1
- Angular 7 latest
- Webpack 4.26.0
- @ngtools/webpack 7.0.5
- Not using angular-cli
- AoT setup
- single page app

This is the error I'm getting when I try to render the layout.html file that's set up for SSR:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at new ApplicationRef (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:43263:37)
at _createClass (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:46296:20)
at _createProviderInstance (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:46258:26)
at initNgModule (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:46190:32)
at new NgModuleRef_ (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:46918:9)
at createNgModuleRef (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:46907:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:48738:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.module.exports.NgModuleFactory_.create (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:49466:25)
at C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:14656:47
at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:139510:26)
at Object.onInvoke (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:14194:37)
at ZoneDelegate.module.exports.ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:139509:32)
at Zone.module.exports.Zone.run (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\public\site\serverBuild\main.js:139260:43)
at NgZone.run (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:14108:32)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:14654:27)
at renderModuleFactory (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\@angular\platform-server\bundles\platform-server.umd.js:1033:43)
at View.module.app.engine (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\modules\clients\site\layout\index.js:60:4)
at View.render (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
at C:\code\lemmsoftWebsite\repo\modules\clients\site\layout\index.js:83:9
```

After much reading through the main.js bundle file, I've pinpointed the problem to the following:

```js
var ApplicationRef = /** @class */ (function () {
    /** @internal */
    function ApplicationRef(_zone, _console, _injector, _exceptionHandler, _componentFactoryResolver, _initStatus) {
        var _this = this;
        this._zone = _zone; // in this method, the _zone argument is {}, so there is no onMicrotaskEmpty method in it => when this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe() is attempted, we get "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"
        this._console = _console;
        this._injector = _injector;
        this._exceptionHandler = _exceptionHandler;
        this._componentFactoryResolver = _componentFactoryResolver;
        this._initStatus = _initStatus;
        this._bootstrapListeners = [];
        this._views = [];
        this._runningTick = false;
        this._enforceNoNewChanges = false;
        this._stable = true;
        // more code
    }
    // more code
}
```

In this method, the _zone argument is {}, so there is no onMicrotaskEmpty method in it => when this._zone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe() is attempted, we get "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined". I kept on digging through the stack trace - this the previous step, where new ApplicationRef is invoked and _zone is passed as {}:

```js
function _createClass(ngModule, ctor, deps) {
    var len = deps.length;
    switch (len) {
        case 0:
            return new ctor();
        case 1:
            return new ctor(resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[0]));
        case 2:
            return new ctor(resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[0]), resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[1]));
        case 3:
            return new ctor(resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[0]), resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[1]), resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[2]));
        default:
            // this is where we get some insight into the cause of the error
            var depValues = new Array(len);
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                depValues[i] = resolveNgModuleDep(ngModule, deps[i]);
            }
            // if we do console.log(deps[0], depValues[0]), which is _zone, we get interesting stuff... 
            return new (ctor.bind.apply(ctor, Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__spread"])([void 0], depValues)))();
    }
}
```

This is where we get some insight into the cause of the error - in the 'default' block of the switch. If we console.log(deps[0], depValues[0]) after the for loop, which is _zone, we get interesting stuff:

```js
// deps[0]
{ flags: 0,
  token:
   { [Function: NgZone]
     isInAngularZone: [Function],
     assertInAngularZone: [Function],
     assertNotInAngularZone: [Function] },
  tokenKey: 'NgZone_29' }
// depValues[0]
{}
```

So, here's the culprit, I thought! 'resolveNgModuleDep' screws it up! So I kept on digging:

```js
function resolveNgModuleDep(data, depDef, notFoundValue) {
    if (notFoundValue === void 0) { notFoundValue = Injector.THROW_IF_NOT_FOUND; }
    var former = setCurrentInjector(data);
    try {
        if (depDef.flags & 8 /* Value */) {
            return depDef.token;
        }
        if (depDef.flags & 2 /* Optional */) {
            notFoundValue = null;
        }
        if (depDef.flags & 1 /* SkipSelf */) {
            return data._parent.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue);
        }
        var tokenKey_1 = depDef.tokenKey;
        switch (tokenKey_1) {
            case InjectorRefTokenKey:
            case INJECTORRefTokenKey:
            case NgModuleRefTokenKey:
                return data;
        }
        var providerDef = data._def.providersByKey[tokenKey_1];
        var injectableDef = void 0;
        if (providerDef) {
            var providerInstance = data._providers[providerDef.index];
            if (providerInstance === undefined) {
                providerInstance = data._providers[providerDef.index] =
                    _createProviderInstance(data, providerDef);
            }
            return providerInstance === UNDEFINED_VALUE ? undefined : providerInstance;
        }
        else if ((injectableDef = getInjectableDef(depDef.token)) && targetsModule(data, injectableDef)) {
            var index = data._providers.length;
            data._def.providersByKey[depDef.tokenKey] = {
                flags: 1024 /* TypeFactoryProvider */ | 4096 /* LazyProvider */,
                value: injectableDef.factory,
                deps: [], index: index,
                token: depDef.token,
            };
            data._providers[index] = UNDEFINED_VALUE;
            return (data._providers[index] =
                _createProviderInstance(data, data._def.providersByKey[depDef.tokenKey]));
        }
        else if (depDef.flags & 4 /* Self */) {
            return notFoundValue;
      }
        // there it is!
        return data._parent.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue);
    }
    finally {
        setCurrentInjector(former);
    }
}
```

There it is! Right before finally, on the line that returns data._parent.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue) - this is where depDef.token (which in our case is NgZone) is passed, notFoundValue is null. The returned object is just {}, hence all the troubles later on.
This is as far as I've managed to get, I've been going back and forth trying to solve it from here, but to no avail. Believe me, I've searched through and through in stackoverflow and just in google; I've read a 1000 medium posts - no success. I don't use angular-cli because I like to customize my webpack config, among other things, but I doubt that's the reason, because angular-cli itself uses webpack under the hood. I'm going to paste a few additional stuff below in  several snippets - my webpack config, the server method where the html and angular bundle is rendered, etc.

```js
// the webpack config

'use strict'

const
 AngularCompilerPlugin = require( "@ngtools/webpack" ).AngularCompilerPlugin,
 BellOnBundlerErrorPlugin = require('bell-on-bundler-error-plugin'),
 BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin,
 path = require('path'),
 ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin'),
 UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'),
 webpack = require('webpack')


module.exports = (config, name) => {
 let includePath = config.clientPath,
  publicPath = path.join(config.publicPath, 'serverBuild'),
  libPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../lib'),
  nodeModulesPath = config.nodeModulesPath,
  include = [includePath]

 return {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'none',
  entry: [
   path.join(includePath, 'polyfills.ts'),
   path.join(includePath, 'vendor.common.ts'),
   path.join(includePath, 'vendor.server.ts'),
   path.join(includePath, 'index.server.ts')
  ],
  output: {
   path: publicPath,
   filename: '[name].js',
   chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
   publicPath: '/dist/',
   libraryTarget: 'commonjs-module'
  },
  resolve: {
   extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
   modules: ['node_modules', libPath]
  },
  module: {
   rules: [
    {
     test: /\.pug$/,
     include: [libPath, includePath],
     use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader']
    },
    {
     test: /\.css$/,
     include: [libPath, nodeModulesPath, includePath],
     exclude: [],
     use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
     test: /\.less$/,
     exclude: [],
     use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    },
    {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     include: [libPath, nodeModulesPath, includePath],
     exclude: [],
     use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    {
     test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
     include: [includePath, libPath],
     use: [{
      loader: '@ngtools/webpack'
     }],
     exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    },
    {
     test: /\.json$/,
     include,
     exclude: [],
     use: ["json2-loader"]
    }
   ]
  },
  stats: 'verbose',
  plugins: [
   // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
   new BellOnBundlerErrorPlugin(),
   new ProgressBarPlugin({
    format: '  build [:bar] (:percent) - (:elapsed seconds)',
    clear: false,
    complete: '#',
    summary: 'true'
   }),
   // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
   new AngularCompilerPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.server.json'),
    entryModule: path.join(includePath, 'app.server.ts#AppServerModule'),
    sourceMap: true
   })
  ]
 }
}
```

```js
// tsconfig.json and tsconfig.server.json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "strictNullChecks": false,
  "lib": [
   "es2015",
   "dom"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types",
   "typings"
  ],
  "types": [
   "hammerjs",
   "node"
  ],
  "paths": {
   "ramster-ui/*": ["lib/ramster-ui/*"]
  }
 },
 "include": [
  "clients/**/*",
  "lib/ramster-ui/**/*"
 ],
 "exclude": [
  "clients/**/*.spec.ts",
  "clients/**/*.e2e.ts"
 ],
 "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "forkChecker": true,
  "useWebpackText": true
 },
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "./compiled",
  "skipMetadataEmit": true
 },
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "buildOnSave": false,
 "atom": {
  "rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
}


{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
 "include": [
  "clients/**/polyfills.ts",
  "clients/**/vendor.common.ts",
  "clients/**/vendor.server.ts",
  "clients/**/app.server.ts",
  "clients/**/index.server.ts",
 ],
 "exclude": [
  "clients/**/index.ts",
  "clients/**/vendor.browser.ts",
  "clients/**/app.ts",
  "clients/**/*.spec.ts",
  "clients/**/*.e2e.ts"
 ],
 "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
  "forkChecker": true,
  "useWebpackText": true
 },
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
  "genDir": "./compiled",
  "skipMetadataEmit": true
 },
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "buildOnSave": false,
 "atom": {
  "rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
}
```

```js
// excerpts from my server setup

// this method is called before the server is started
 setup() {
  const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require(path.join(__dirname, '../../../../public/site/serverBuild', 'main'))
  // LAZY_MODULE_MAP is undefined for now
  this.module.app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
   renderModuleFactory(
    AppServerModuleNgFactory, {}
   ).then((html) => callback(null, html), (error) => callback(error))
  })
  this.module.app.set('view engine', 'html')
 }

// the method returned by "loadLayout" is mounted in expressjs
 loadLayout() {
  const {module} = this
  return function* (req, res, next) {
   try {
    res.render(path.join('../../../../public/site/layout.html'), {req, res})
   } catch (e) {
    req.locals.error = e
    next()
   }
  }
 }
```

```js
// polyfills.ts
import 'core-js/es6'
import 'reflect-metadata'


// vendor.common.ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'
import 'popper.js'

import '@angular/common'
import '@angular/core'
import '@angular/flex-layout'
import '@angular/forms'
import '@angular/material'
import '@angular/router'


// vendor.server.ts
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
import '@angular/platform-server'


// index.server.ts
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 enableProdMode()
}
export * from './app.server.ngfactory'


// app.server.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server'

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    ServerModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
class AppServerModule {}

export {AppServerModule}
```

You'll see that I've trimmed down the server-side app to the very basics, so I can eliminate the error being caused by something I've written.
Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, can you move `import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'` to the top, as in include it as the very first import.

Comment: Thanks :) It's the first thing I tried - it was on top of the polyfills file before. Sadly, no difference :(

Comment: What the context of the original throw: `...clients\site\layout\index.js:83:9` ?

Comment: It's the rendering line from my server setup snippet - res.render(path.join('../../../../public/site/layout.html'), {req, res})

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction on github?

Comment: Working on it..

Comment: @RumenRumenov did you ever manage to figure it out?

Comment: Not yet sadly, I'll try the latest comment and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @RumenRumenov, did something change since March? I am currently struggling with the very same issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I'm running into the same issue :(

Comment: Sadly - no. I decided to migrate to Angular 8 and see if it works then, still haven't had the time to do so, but will get around to it soon and post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZoneJS does not work properly as an AMD module. You are using the SystemJS AMD extra and zone.js is bundled to UMD format -- this results in Zone being used as an AMD module which triggers the broken behavior

Full explanation, and issue on zone.js - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36827

Minimal demonstration of the problem - https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-antonelli-2kusz?file=/index.html

Workaround - https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shape-18x7b

Answer (score -1):

webpack must be   `mode: 'development'`,
If you can reproduce the problem with fork https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter - a can help.